# values の入力順で row_number を振る方法

Tags: postgresql

プログラム側から固定値を入力してデータベースをひいて値を検索したいんですが
返却する時にプログラム側の入力順で返却したいです
なので values の入力順でIDをふりたいんですがどうすればいいでしょうか

row_number には over が必要なんですが

```
select row_number() over(order by(x)), * from (values (2),(1),(3)) as v(x);
 row_number | x
------------+---
          1 | 1
          2 | 2
          3 | 3
(3 rows)
```

とかやると値で並び変わってしまいます

プログラム側で ID をふっておくのも手なんですが
大量のデータを１度に変換することもありクエリ長制限にかかりにくいように短い方が嬉しいので
データベース側でいい方法はありませんか？

Comment: `select row_number() over (), * from (values (2),(1),(3)) as v;`で目的は達成できますか？

Comment: できました！　over って中空でいいんですね

Comment: 厳密に仕様を確認したわけではないですがおそらくNGです。明示的にソート順が指定されない限り順序は保証されないのが一般的な挙動です。

Comment: そうなのですね。では回答削除して引き続き回答募集状態に戻しておきます。ただ環境依存なのかたまたまかもしれないですがいまのところ自分の環境 (AWS Aurora postgresql) ではうまくはいってるようです

Comment: そもそも「プログラムの入力値にそのまま行番号をつける」がやりたいことではないと思います。「クエリ超制限にかからないように」というのも何を気にされているのかよくわからないので、まずやりたいことを具体的にされた方がいいと思います